# Is there any way to use scanner front panel to scan to linux?

Tags: smart-home, raspberry-pi, networking, linux

I have a EPSON WF-3540 MFP. I want to use it to scan files directly to my NAS. As this device does not support scan to FTP or any other network share, I thought of using a lightweight linux device (e.g. Raspberry Pi) as a scan server.
Sadly, I can't find any possiblity to initiate a scan via the front panel of my device. All tutorials (e.g. for SANE package) implicate that I have to initate the scan from GUI or CLI on the server. However this kind of contradicts the purpose of a small headless scan server.

Does anybody know how to initiate scans from the device when connected to a linux server?

Comment: Getting a script to run a CLI tool when you push a button is not too tricky. A raspberry pi has plenty of GPIO pins you use for the button or you can get a load of 1 button keyboards.

Comment: does the scanner support "scan to computer"

Comment: @hardillb: Thanks for the suggestion. I am considering this as a solution, if it won't work otherwise. However i fear I would need several buttons to cover all the settings possibilities the front panel would give me (different resolutions, flat-bed / ADF, SW / color, Simplex / Duplex).

Comment: @jsotola: Yes it supports scan to computer. Upon selecting the following possibilities are "Use USB connection" or select of the Computers reachable over the network to scan to.
When is choose USB, an error occurs statig that USB connection is not found (even when installed SANE drivers). Under the network devices, only my Windows PC shows up. I think this may be because of a beforehand registration of this Windows machine by means of a Epson specific tool (Epson - Event manager). Sadly, this tool seems to not exist for Linux.

Comment: the scan button probably sends a broadcast over the LAN ... a program on the receiving computer listens for this broadcast and starts up the scan program on the computer ... you may be able to run a scan button daemon on the Raspberry Pi ... you should be able to see broadcasts on the lan by using wireshark

Comment: @jsotola: Nice suggestion. Thanks! Never got the idea to use WireShark on this. I'll try to sniff its communication tonight. Maybe I can also sniff the communication when Epson Event Manager registers the device on the scanner.